# Данные о "загрузке" GPU

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ли возможность в .Net получить данные о %% загрузки GPU?

Например следующий код позволяет получить усреднённые данные о %% загрузки CPU за последнюю секунду:

```
PerformanceCounter cpumonitor = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time","_Total");
var CurCPULoad= cpucounter.NextValue().ToString()
```

Что-то аналогичное для GPU возможно получить? ( В перечислении возможных источников данных для PerformanceCounter я ничего подходящего не нашёл... возможно просмотрел что-то... )

Comment: смотри в сторону WMI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В процессе поиска ответа на вопрос получил следующие результаты:

Средствами операционной системы (WMI, System Diagnostics и пр) получить данные о загрузке GPU не получится. Но в целом WMI весьма и весьма ценный ресурс для получения прочих данных о состоянии системы (и не только, там много чего полезного можно получить). Для удобства работы с WMI рекомендую использовать [Вот эту полезную програмулину](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8572) Умеет генерить код запроса ресурса на C#.

Но тем не менее решение всё же было найдено. Т.е. был найден проект на C# в котором данный функционал реализован. [Вот Он на GH](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor)
Если в кратце, то для ATI и NVidia используются свои API предоставляемые вместе с драйверами оборудования. (как быть с Intell графикой пока не нашёл)